# Ruby array to sub-arrays based on element values

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to parse a text file and hoping to get some Ruby help turning an array into a series of sub-arrays based on the searching and filtering of certain values, mainly the presence of zeros. In this case, each sub-array should contain only one pair of 00Mom and 00Dad plus the elements without zeros that follow (eg. kids) but not including the next instance of 00Mom and 00Dad -- which would go into the next sub-array.

For example, with this array:

```
array1 = ["00Mom1", "00Dad1", "Kid1", "Kid2", "00Mom2", "00Dad2", "Child1", "Child2", "00Mom3", "Youngin1"]
```

I'd like to output this array of sub-arrays:

```
array2 = [["00Mom1", "00Dad1", "Kid1", "Kid2"], ["00Mom2", "00Dad2", "Child1", "Child2"], ["00Mom3", "Youngin1"]]
```

My first thought was to use the "00"s in a count but I cannot get it to work. I'm thinking the solution might be in using a nested array but not sure. This is what I have so far.

```
array1 = ["00Mom1", "00Dad1", "Kid1", "Kid2", "00Mom2", "00Dad2", "Child1", "Child2", "00Mom3", "Youngin1"]
```

```
zero_count = 0
array2 = []
new_array = []
subarray_count = 0

array1.map do |z|

  if z[0] == "0"
    zero_count = zero_count + 1
  end

  if zero_count == 3
    new_array = array1.slice(0, subarray_count)
    zero_count = 1
    subarray_count = 0
    array2 << new_array

  end

  subarray_count = subarray_count + 1

end

p array2
```

Output:

```
[["00Mom1", "00Dad1", "Kid1", "Kid2"], ["00Mom1", "00Dad1", "Kid1", "Kid2"]]
```

But I need:

```
[["00Mom1", "00Dad1", "Kid1", "Kid2"], ["00Mom2", "00Dad2", "Child1", "Child2"], ["00Mom3", "Youngin1"]]
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is order guaranteed? e.g. always Mom or Dad, then N kids and then repeat? if so this seems to work `array1.chunk_while {|a,b|a =~ /(Mom|Dad)/ || b !~ /(Mom|Dad)/  }.to_a`

Comment: That works beautifully. Thanks a lot. As you can likely tell, I'm new to coding and Ruby. Is the forward slash a regex thing?

Comment: Yes it is Regular Expression literal syntax

Comment: While Enumerable#chunk_while will work, this seems like an X/Y problem. What's your actual text file look like, and why are you slurping it into an array first?